# Custom Text Classification Model - Labels for component 'textcat' not initialized

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I am trying to create a custom model on some training data. For this, I want to train a custom text classification model. This is my approach (simplified):

First I have some training data, that looks like this:

```py
train_data = [('Some text....', {'cats': {'POSITIVE': True, 'NEGATIVE': False}}), ("Another text......", {'cats': {'POSITIVE': True, 'NEGATIVE': False}})]
```

Then I try to create a blank model with a custom text classification:

```
# Load model
nlp=spacy.blank("en")
#Create a new pipeline
category = nlp.create_pipe('textcat')
#Add our two labels
category.add_label("POSITIVE")
category.add_label("NEGATIVE")
nlp.add_pipe('textcat')

# Train the model:
train_model(nlp, train_data)
```

The `train_model` method looks like the below:

```py
#Train the model:
def train_model(nlp, TRAINING_DATA, output_dir='C:\\Users\\Oliver\\Documents\\PythonAPI\\'):
    # Start the training
    nlp.begin_training()

    # Loop for 10 iterations
    for _ in range(10):
        # Shuffle the training data
        random.shuffle(TRAINING_DATA)
        losses = {}

        # Batch the examples and iterate over them
        for batch in spacy.util.minibatch(TRAINING_DATA, size=1):
            texts = [nlp(text) for text, entities in batch]
            annotations = [{"cats": entities} for text, entities in batch]
            nlp.update(texts, annotations, losses=losses)

    nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
    print("Saved model to", output_dir)
```

The above code gives me the below error:

> ValueError: [E143] Labels for component 'textcat' not initialized. This can be fixed by calling add_label, or by providing a representative batch of examples to the component's `initialize` method.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using spaCy v3, but writing code like it's version 2. You see in the version 3 spaCy do not have method called .begin_training() and therefore there's no textcat. Try reading the documentation, the method .begin_training() now called textcat.initialize()